# OpenCV waitkey() maximum finite time

Tags: opencv

I know `waitKey(0)` waits indefinitely for a key press, and `waitKey(600000)`should wait for 10 minutes which prompts the question, what is the maximum *finite* time (in milliseconds) that `waitKey()` will wait for? My guess is the biggest number that can be coded in the program.

Comment: That would seem to be a pretty good guess. There doesn't seem to be any limitation on the argument other than it has to be an `int` and it has to be greater than zero.

Comment: if (waitKey(biggestFiniteNumber)=="") waitKey (biggestFiniteNumber)  will wait 2 x for the longest finite time. although there is a small chance that the keypress will be missed during the if -statement.

Comment: `waitKey` takes an int as a parameter, so assuming a 32-bit int, you can represent up to 2,147,483,647 in ms, which is about 596 hours. I'm not about to try it out though...

Comment: alrikai seems the most sensible answer. It's only 24 days if you want to run it and find out :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`waitKey()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) doc, the delay parameter is `int`. `int`'s max value is 2,147,483,647.  2,147,483,647 ms is 596.523 hours or about 24.86 days.